# include a php file which is part of custom plugin directory

Tags: php, wordpress

`I have created a plugin called "add menu to dash board". For that I have created folder addmenu in wordpress's plugin folder.
In that folder my main php file of the plugin and the other`entry.php` file exists.

Through the plugin I have created a menu & submenu, info & entry, link resp.
Now I want to redirect to `entry.php` file when submenu(entry) gets clicked,  because there I have a simple html form from which I want to insert data in a database.

So could anybody  help me on this?

I have read out require_once(),require_once() & include_once(), include(). But I don't get it.

```
    function register_my_custom_menu_page() 
    {
        //add_menu_page('custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'add_users', 'custompage', '_custom_menu_page', null, 6); 

        add_menu_page("Info", "Info", 0, "info-slug", "infoPageFunction","", 6);
        add_submenu_page("info-slug", "Entry", "Entry", 0, "entry-slug", "entryPageFunction");
        add_submenu_page("info-slug", "Link", "Link", 0, "link-slug", "linkPageFunction");
    }
```

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

```
    function entryPageFunction()
    {
      //~ echo '<script>
                //~ window.location="/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/addmenu/entry.php";
            //~ </script>';
            require_once( add_Cmenu__PLUGIN_DIR . 'entry.php' );
    }
```

I have tried this abve code

also tried this :-`include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'add_Cmenu/entry.php');`

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is... Do you need help inserting the menu or how to handle form data?

Comment: Please add the code you've already tried.

Comment: no i have inserted menu.

Comment: Now I only want to redirect to the php file when I clicked on the submenu called"entry"..... the menu i have created id like Info(main menu),entry&link(submenu)

Comment: Please help me somebody......@mjk I have inserted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This.

```
 function add_menu_info(){

                   add_menu_page('Info', 'Info', 'manage_options', 'Info', 'InfoFun');
                   add_submenu_page('Info', 'Entry', 'Entry', 'manage_options', 'entry', 'entryFun');
            }

        add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu_info');


    function  entryFun(){

        include(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'entry.php');
        }
```

Comment: Well Come Dear @sanket,